# Play first youtube embedded video from a list of link using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, youtube, youtube-api

I am calling a loop to generate a list of link of youtube embedded video. When I click on any of the links, the related video is opened in iFrame. But the problem is, when I first load the page, it does not shows any video in an iFrame nor even the iFrame. I need to click on a link to load a video. I want to load the first video of the list automatically when I load the page.

iFrame of the video:

```
    <h4 id="videoTitle"></h4>
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe id="frame" name="frame" width="560" height="315" src="about:blank" frameborder="0" 
            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
            allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
    </div>
```

This is the loop to generate list of videos, I am using laravel, so this is how the code looks like:

```
@foreach($topic->videos as $video)
    <li>
        <a href="{{ $video->url }}" class="ytLink">Play Video</a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Here is my jQuery code:

```
<script>
    $('.ytLink').on('click', function (e) {
         $('#frame')[0].src = $(this).attr('href') + '?autoplay=1';
         e.preventDefault();
         $('#videoTitle').text($(this).text());
    });
</script>
```

Can anyone help me how to load the first video automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I triggered a click on your first link when the document is loaded.

I use the `$(document).ready()` function to get your code execute when the document is loaded and ready to use.
I pasted your code inside this function. After I find your first link with `$('.ytLink').eq(0)` then I use the `.trigger('click')` on this element. So this trigger will run when the document is loaded.

More info about the [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) function.

And more info about the [.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.ytLink').on('click', function (e) {
         $('#frame')[0].src = $(this).attr('href') + '?autoplay=1';
         e.preventDefault();
         $('#videoTitle').text($(this).text());
    });
  $('.ytLink').eq(0).trigger('click');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 id="videoTitle"></h4>
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe id="frame" name="frame" width="560" height="315" src="about:blank" frameborder="0" 
            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
            allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
    </div>
 
 
 <li>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vhh_GeBPOhs" class="ytLink">Play Video</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vhh_GeBPOhs" class="ytLink">Play Video</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vhh_GeBPOhs" class="ytLink">Play Video</a>
    </li>
```